# Python - Printing to GUI instead of terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

Very new to CustomTkinter, and I'm trying to create a GUI app that returns a prediction of your written tweet.The output happens at the terminal, and I'd like it to print in the GUI instead of terminal, if anyone could help me it would be so appreciated!
All I am trying to do is to print my results on the GUI, I'm aware that printing goes straight to the terminal but I'm not sure how to figure this one out...

This my code

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from scipy.special import softmax


app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("700x500")
app.title("Twitter Sentiment Analyser")

frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app)
frame_1.pack(pady=20, padx=60, fill="both", expand=True)

label_1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_1, justify=tkinter.LEFT, text="Twitter Sentiment Analyses System")
# label_1.pack(pady=12, padx=10)
# label_1.pack(side="left", pady=12)
label_1.place(x=20, y=20)

tweet = input()
tweet1 = customtkinter.CTkTextbox(master= frame_1, height= 100, width=380)
tweet1.pack(pady=12, padx=10)
tweet1.place(y= 150, x=100)
tweet1 = tweet

# def predict():
    # p = entry_1.get("1.0",'end-1c')
    # label_2 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame_1, text="The Tweet is: ")
tweet_words = []

for word in tweet.split(' '):
    if word.startswith('@') and len(word) > 1:
        word = '@user'
    
    elif word.startswith('http'):
        word = "http"
    tweet_words.append(word)

tweet_proc = " ".join(tweet_words)

# load model and tokenizer
roberta = "cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment"

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(roberta)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(roberta)

labels = ['Negative', 'Neutral', 'Positive']

# sentiment analysis
encoded_tweet = tokenizer(tweet_proc, return_tensors='pt')
# output = model(encoded_tweet['input_ids'], encoded_tweet['attention_mask'])
output = model(**encoded_tweet)

scores = output[0][0].detach().numpy()
scores = softmax(scores)
def pre():
    for i in range(len(scores)):
    
        l = labels[i]
        s = scores[i]
        print(l,s)

buutton_1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame_1, command=pre, text="Predict")
buutton_1.pack(pady=12, padx=10)
buutton_1.place(y=290, x=90)
```

Answer (score 0):

this will help to undestand tkinter

```
import tkinter

#create root 
app = tkinter.Tk()
app.geometry('1280x720')
#create textbox for get input in gui  
input_text_box = tkinter.Text(app ,width=700 ,height=300 ,fg='#ffffff' ,bg="#101010")
input_text_box.place(x=0)

#create textbox for get output in gui
output_text_box = tkinter.Text(app ,width=700 ,height=200 ,fg='#ffffff' ,bg="#101010")
output_text_box.place(y=350 ,x=0)


def prediction_tweet(input_text):
    predicted_tweet = input_text
    
    # you can add your process for get prediction text 
    return predicted_tweet

input_text = ""
def display():
    global input_text
    
    #read values from textbox 
    input_text_new  = input_text_box.get("0.0","end")

    if input_text != input_text_new :
        input_text = input_text_new 
        
        #get predicted tweet
        predicted_tweet = prediction_tweet(input_text)
        
        #delete all text in output textbox # need to reset textbox before display
        output_text_box.delete('0.0','end')

        #display predicted tweet 
        output_text_box.insert('end',predicted_tweet)
    #loop
    app.after(100,display)
     #         ^
     #     100 milisecond delay on loop 
#call def display
display()


app.mainloop()
```